# WPF Keep textbox focussed while pressing tab key

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a WPF application where we are supposed to shift focus from one button to another by pressing the TAB key.

All is fine, but for a specific page, there is a textbox which is always focused so that the user can type in it immediately. But now, when I press TAB, the focus is shifted to the button (which is as per requirement) but as the focus is lost from the textbox, I cannot type anymore.

I want to have a behavior where I can keep the Keyboard focus on textbox but should be able to control the buttons using TAB key as well. In a way, I need to have focus on textbox and the buttons at the same time. Is this possible?

Tried the `FocusManager.IsFocusScope = "true"`, but this did not help.

Comment: You can try to use `PreviewKeyUp/Down` on a parent container (you will get those disregards which child has keyboard focus) and then route `Tab` presses to buttons and the rest - to a textbox.